# Linq FindWhere clause and boolean filters?

Tags: c#, linq

I have to add the following to this filter,

"If the CountryID passed in equals (999) then the search should search all countries, and not filter by country."

what I currently have is this, which totally confuses me.

```
var query = rep.
    FindWhere(c => 
        (
            countryID.HasValue == false || 
            c.CityID == null || 
            c.Countries.ID == countryID
        )
        && 
        (
            mediaTypeID == 0 || 
            c.MediaTypeID == mediaTypeID
        ) 
        && c.Active);
```

I'm assuming that if any on the conditions in the first parantheses is true then it will match against all countries?! if so then I can add an extra expression in the first parantheses to check for countryID 999?

ps. FindWhere is:

```
public IQueryable<T> FindWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) 
{
    return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rep.FindWhere(c => (c.CityID == null || !countryID.HasValue ||
                    countryID == 999 || c.Countries.ID == countryID) &&
                   (mediaTypeID == 0 || c.MediaTypeID == mediaTypeID))
```

BTW your conditions logic is really hard to understand. Consider to refactor your code.

Answer (score 3):

> Im assuming that if any on the conditions in the first parantheses is true then it will match against all countries?! if so then I can add an extra expression in the first parantheses to check for countryID 999?

This should work.  Right now, the predicate requires that any of the first three conditions is true (`countryID` is `null` or the country specified, or the city is `null`), and then checks for either of the second conditions.

Adding a check against 999 would allow the first criteria to pass always if you used 999 for country checking, effectively "removing" the filter.

That being said, I personally would prefer to break this up.  Since you're already using `IQueryable<T>`, you can selectively add filters:

```
var query = rep.FindWhere(c => c.Active);
if (mediaType != 0)
    query = query.Where(c => c.MediaTypeID == mediaTypeID);
if (countryID != 999)
    query = query.Where(c => countryID.HasValue == false || c.CityID == null || c.Countries.ID == countryID);
```

This is more efficient (you only add the filter if required), but also easier to understand.